# Stop page reload on javascript form validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Site: http://bit.ly/15JAx04

The above link has a form at the bottom of the page. When submitted withut values/invalid values the page validation reloads the page. How can I get it to just show the red validation errors and remain at the bottom without reloading to top of page? The only JS for this page I know of is below.

```
    function Check()
{  
  
  var returnValue = true;
  
  if ($('#dnn_ctr612_XModPro_ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_name').val() == 'Full name')
  {      
      $('#dnn_ctr612_XModPro_ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_name').val(''); 
      returnValue = false;
  }  
  
  if ($('#dnn_ctr612_XModPro_ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_company').val() == 'Company')
  {      
      $('#dnn_ctr612_XModPro_ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_company').val(''); 
      returnValue = false;
  }  
  
  if ($('#dnn_ctr612_XModPro_ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_email').val() == 'Email')
  {      
      $('#dnn_ctr612_XModPro_ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_email').val(''); 
      returnValue = false;
  }  
  
  if ($('#dnn_ctr612_XModPro_ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_phone').val() == 'Phone (optional)')
  {      
      $('#dnn_ctr612_XModPro_ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_phone').val('');       
  }  
  
  if ($('#dnn_ctr612_XModPro_ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_message').val() == 'Your message')
  {      
      $('#dnn_ctr612_XModPro_ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_message').val(''); 
      returnValue = false;
  }  
  
  return returnValue;
  
 }
```

Comment: prevent default submit event of the form.

Comment: using javascript is the key indeed. A quick note though : if any of your usercontrols or controls changes name , your whole javascript will be discarded... you may want to use the "clientId" property or so

Comment: You should do something like `var name = $('#name').val(); if (name == 'Full name' || $.trim(name) == '') {}`

Answer (score 1):

Use this method  -- >

in your form give action="return check();"

Where check() is a function in javascript,

```
Function check()
{
if(your_form_values_condition)
{
return true;
}
else
{
alert("Please fill form correctly!");
return false;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to accept `return` value in inline event handlers

You have in your code:

```
<input type="submit" name="dnn$ctr632$XModPro$ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$ctl11" value="Send" onclick="Check();Web...
```

But you need

```
<input type="submit" name="dnn$ctr632$XModPro$ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$ctl11" value="Send" onclick="Web...; return Check();">
```

Or add `Check()` function into `<form>` element.

```
<form onsubmit="return Check();">
```

So this will submit form only if `Check()` function will return `true`.

Or using jQuery with this simple code:

```
$( '#Form' ).submit( function() {
    if( Check() ) return true;
    else return false;
});
```

But don't forget to remove `Check()` call from submit button in `onclick` handler as you will have in that case duplicate error messages.

Answer (score 0):

use `onclick="return Check()"` like this -

```
<input type="submit" name="dnn$ctr632$XModPro$ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$ctl11" value="Send" onclick="return Check()"
```